# Why did bash (or PuTTY) interpret the two characters 'cd' as the single character '㏅'?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, unicode, putty

I ssh'd into a CentOS VM today through PuTTY -- right after I logged in and got a bash shell, I tried to `cd` to another directory, but the displaying of what I typed lagged a bit, and then instead of 'cd' it displayed the single character '㏅'. I had already hit enter, so bash humorously notified me that the command `㏅` was not found:

[image]

After that it interpreted any further `cd`s correctly.

After some research I discovered the `㏅` character is the Unicode character "Square CD", part of the [CJK Compatibility block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility), meant to provide compatibility with east Asian character sets, and specifically this character represents the SI unit [candela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela), the base unit of luminous intensity, which I just thought is awesome.

Anyway, no idea how to reporoduce this. I tried a couple times re-logging in and very quickly typing 'cd' but it interpreted it correctly each time.

My PuTTY version is: `PuTTYTray p0.67-t029` (which I guess I should update)

Output of `uname -a`: `Linux xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And bash version is : `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Not sure whether it would be bash or PuTTY where the "translation" happened, or even why it would've happened... I guess there must be some feature where somehow multiple characters that correspond to the meaning of a single character get "collapsed" into the single one..? or something? The 2 bytes of 'c' and 'd' don't combine to '㏅' either (I checked!) (though it would be extremely cool if they actually did)

Anyway, if anybody can explain I'd like to know!

Comment: This most likely has to do with your windows input method / character composing facilities. I find highly doubtful that either putty, ssh or bash had any hand in it.

Comment: @mosvy I just had that thought! I think that makes the most sense. still a weird and interesting thing

Comment: just curious what history logged ???

Comment: @MarkStewart well weirdly enough all I see in .bash_history is the actual 2-character `cd` command. `㏅` isn't in there. I'm not 100% sure if it didn't log the `㏅` one, or if it logged it as `cd`

Comment: That is weird.  If you figure it out post I am curious about this for some reason.

Comment: Also just had this happen to me, and it appears in my history after logging in again. No clue how I managed it, but I think I fumbled the `alt+gr` key, but can't reproduce it. Note that I had run other commands before this so was not the first of the session.

Comment: I think I figured this out, seems like it is indeed due to my IME. I have Japanese as an alternate input method -- if you use the hiragana input and type `cd`, the first suggested character is the `㏅` symbol. You still have to Tab/down arrow to it and hit enter (not sure how I managed to do that so fast, or if something else happened), but that's gotta be it. I've definitely accidently typed a bunch of garbled Japanese nonsense from forgetting to change the IME back lol... Reproducing it now, it's in my history.